# Json request in background Async task not returning data

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

I am new here and i would like some help regarding an app i am trying to develop for a friend.

The problem i am encountering is that i am trying to make a Json Request every 15 minutes in a background thread that will not be affected by the main process. So when the Main app is killed i still want a thread to keep checking for an update on a website.The problem is I get no data(from the Json request) in the notification i print. If i run the code in the main class i get data printed.

Please see the code below of the service i have created.
P.S. This is my first app i am trying to develop so i am sorry in advance if i have stupid mistakes..:)

```
public class MyService extends JobService {


BackgroundTask backgroundTask;

NotificationCompat.Builder notify;
private static final int notify_ID = 258799;

@Override
public boolean onStartJob(final JobParameters jobParameters) {

    notify = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notify.setAutoCancel(true);

    backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask()
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s){

            notify.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
            notify.setTicker("This is a ticker");
            notify.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
            notify.setContentTitle("Stream check");
            notify.setContentText(s);
            //Build notification
            NotificationManager mn = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mn.notify(notify_ID,notify.build());

            jobFinished(jobParameters, false);
        }
    };

    backgroundTask.execute();
    return true; 
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
    return true; 
}


//new background class on new thread
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>
{
    String result;
    String url = "www.google.com"; 

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids){

        RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        JsonObjectRequest objectRequest= new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.GET,
                url,
                null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        //Log.e("Rest response: ",response.toString());
                        result = response.toString();

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("Rest error response: ", error.toString());
                    }
                }
        );

        requestQueue.add(objectRequest);
        return result;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you don't need the async task. The request queue is asynchronous. You can replace your `onPostExecute` block by implementing the `Response.Listener` instead.

Comment: Your URL from where you're trying to fetch the data is different, right?
It's not google.com, right?